# Issue with SSAS: Definition of a set causes a circular reference

Tags: ssas, mdx

This is ok and returns the sum of the default measure for the past 30 days:

```
SELECT
FROM    [OurCube]  
WHERE   (
        closingperiod(
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].defaultmember
            ):
        closingperiod(
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].defaultmember
            ).ITEM(0).LAG(30)
            )
```

How do I transfer the set of dates in the `WHERE` clause into the `WITH` clause ?
I attempted the following but it creates the error message detailed:

```
WITH 
    SET [30Days] AS
    {
    closingperiod(
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].defaultmember
            ):
    closingperiod(
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].defaultmember
        ).ITEM(0).LAG(30)
    }
SELECT
FROM  [OurCube]  
WHERE (
      [30Days]
      )
```

> Executing the query ...
>   The definition of the 30Days set contains a circular reference.
>   Execution complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a limitation of SSAS and has something to do with the execution processing of the different parts of the query; even using a SUB-QUERY (i.e., FROM ( SELECT ... )) instead of a WHERE would not solve the issue.

You can define your set at schema level :

```
CREATE STATIC SET [OurCube].[30Days] as ...
```

Or depending on your client application at session level:

```
CREATE SESSION STATIC SET SET [OurCube].[30Days] as ...
```

Comment: +1 thanks Marc. These two topics you mention `SUB-QUERY` and differing levels of declaration are new to me and sound worth exploring. Off topic: how do you render the results of your `MDX` ?

Comment: interesting - How do you build your cubes if not using `SSAS`? so no rendering the results in `SSRS` or in a non-MS cube-based tool?